# Why is this inserting a string into my table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `contacts` that has a field `arrayOfMembers` (JSON format) and a table `users` with field `userId` (int).

```
$recipientId=getUserIdForEmail($recipientEmail);
addUserIdToContactsMemberIds($noteId, $recipientId);

function addUserIdToContactsMemberIds($noteId, $userId)
     {
          $memberData=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactId='$contactId'");
          $memberResultData = mysql_fetch_assoc($memberData);
          $arrayOfMemberIds=json_decode($memberResultData['arrayOfMembers']);
          $arrayOfMemberIds[]=$userId;
          $sendback=json_encode($arrayOfMemberIds);
          mysql_query("UPDATE notes SET arrayOfMembers='$sendback' where contactId='$contactId'");
     }

function getUserIdForEmail($email)
    {
         $data=mysql_query("SELECT userId FROM users WHERE userEmail='$email'");
         $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
         return $result["userId"];
    }
```

However, the `$userId` is being stored as a string with quotations, so that where if I originally have [1], after adding a new userId, it looks like this [1,"2"] even though it should look like [1,2].

If I manually enter an int value in the line: `$arrayOfMemberIds[]=$userId;` and put `$arrayOfMemberIds[]=5`, then I get the correct result, that is [1,5]. Why is this happening?

Comment: How do I pass as an int?

Comment: Same way you pass a string, only you pass an int instead.

Comment: You don't. This is PHP. You just do it.

Comment: Can you post an answer showing how?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams your solution is neither correct nor helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an issue with the ID being a string (in most cases, it isn't a big deal), then simply use `intval()`:

```
$arrayOfMemberIds[] = intval($userId);
```

*or*

```
return intval($result["userId"]);
```

### Why's it a string?

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns all values as a `string`, regardless of the type in the database. Straight from PHP documentation:

> *Returns an associative array of **strings*** that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. - http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. Is there also a way to redefine my methods so that I don't have to use intval?

Comment: @mohabitar, I'm fairly confident that the MySQLi functions return the correct type (if there is a corresponding type in PHP -- e.g. no `date` type, so it becomes a `string`). Also, you could make sure to use `intval()` whenever you select `int` columns from the database. However, inserting a `string` into an `int` column in a MySQL database isn't a big deal and it will be automatically converted for you. The only time you'll really run into an issue is if you're using `===` and `!==` (or checking type specifically). Personally, I'd suggest using MySQLi as it also offers prepared statements.